# i'm having two different run time errors

Tags: c#, runtime-error

i get two run time errors first({"Sequence contains more than one element"} ==> System.InvalidOperationException )  when there is more than once it occurred and also when i want to delete what i wrote in my textbox
what should  i do?

here is my code

```
 private AutoCompleteStringCollection GetLinqDataSourceForString(string p)
    {
        var c = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        c.Add( Getauto(p));
        return c;
    }

   private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
          txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = GetLinqDataSourceForString(txtSearch.Text);
      }
```

and this one is in another layer to get info from data Base

```
    public string AutoUpdate(string _search)
    {
        using (var context = new Phone_BookEntities1())
        {
            var c = (from d in context.Cantacts
                     where d.Cantact1.StartsWith(_search)
                     select d.Cantact1).SingleOrDefault();
            return c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show `Getauto(string ...)`?

Comment: Probably `where d.Cantact1.StartsWith(_search)` is matching multiple items, hence *Sequence contains more than one element*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/265419/james-barrass                    public string GetAutoupdate(string _search)
        {
            Ref_Model = new Model._Model();
            return Ref_Model.AutoUpdate(_search);
        } 
        #endreg

Comment: @arghya-c What should i do??

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault` will throw if your sequence has more than one element. If your intention is to get the first matching contact in your table, use `FirstOrDefault` instead.